# Google Plus in an ASP.NET User Control

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-4.0

I have an ASP.NET 4.0 home page which displays about 20 product listings. Each product listing leads to a url in the format: `/DisplayProduct.aspx?ProdID=X`

I want to display how many Google Plus and ReTweets each product listing received, in front of each listing. How can I do it in the best optimized manner and without affecting the page load speed too much. What scripts have to be used?

Here's the User Control with the code

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ProductListing.ascx.cs" Inherits="Controls.ProductListing" %>

<asp:GridView ID="gvProducts" runat="server"  AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
   DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="objProds" PageSize="10" ShowHeader="False"
   OnRowDataBound="gvProducts_RowDataBound" OnRowCommand="gvProducts_RowCommand"
    >
   <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product List">
         <HeaderStyle  />
         <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="plist">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;">
    <tr><td>               
               <div class="productname">
               <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="hypName" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'
                  NavigateUrl='<%# "~/DisplayProduct.aspx?ID=" + Eval("ProdID") %>'/> 
               </div>               
            </td> </tr>
            </table>
             <div class="productdesc">
             <b>Description: </b>
            <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="lblDesc" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' />
            </div>
            </div>
         </ItemTemplate>         
      </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>   
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like that

```
<!-- Place this tag where you want the +1 button to render -->
<g:plusone size="small" annotation="none" href="http://www.yourwebsite.com/DisplayProduct.aspx?ProdID=<%# Eval("Name") %>"></g:plusone>
```

The above is what you want to repeat for each product with a different url pointing to that  product page.

And the below script should not be repeated.

```
<!-- Place this render call where appropriate -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: should I add this script in the user control? Where does it fit? Moreover the product url is getting created dynamically. So can I specify it in the >g:plusone script

Comment: you should assign href in the same way as you set NavigateUrl in the link. Script should ideally be placed at the bottom of the page (so browser will display content first and then take care about scripts)

Comment: I would keep this script at the bottom of your page as you might have g+ buttons somewhere else.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work - <g:plusone size="small" annotation="none" href="http://www.yourwebsite.com/DisplayProduct.aspx?ProdID=" + Eval("ProdID") ></g:plusone>

Comment: see the updated post. I replaced X with your ProdID. Let me know if you still have any issues with it